# startTranscriptionJob error: "The specified S3 bucket can't be accessed. Make sure you have write permission on the bucket and try your request again"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I have a lambda in account A that tries transcribing a recording in account B. I attempted to perform this action via console and it works but when I try to do it via AWS SDK v3 (node js) I get the following error: The specified S3 bucket can't be accessed. Make sure you have write permission on the bucket and try your request again. I made the bucket public but I got the same error. I don't know what could be the issue and how can I transcribe a recording in another account via lambda. The code is working for a bucket in the same account. Any help would be appreciated.